# Is it possible to figure out WHAT is changing in a RowChanging event?

Tags: .net, events, datatable, datarow

The `DataTable` class has `RowChanging` as well as `RowChanged` events, which is convenient (for those of us foolish enough to be using the `DataTable` class in the first place). Event handlers for these events take a parameter of type `DataRowChangeEventArgs`, whose properties comprise a `DataRowAction` (Add, Change, Delete, etc.) and the `DataRow` being changed or having just changed.

Is there any way to actually know which fields of the `DataRow` are being changed (in the `RowChanging` event) or have just changed (in the `RowChanged` event)? If not, is it possible to get this information in some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know which fields are changed, I think you're better of using ColumnChanged http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columnchanged.aspx or ColumnChanging http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columnchanging.aspx.

In both cases there is an example to get the old and new values.

Comment: Man, that is not what I thought it was at all. What a misleading name (in my opinion)! Seems like it should be `FieldChanged` or something like that.

Comment: @DanTao I feel you bro. Had the exact same situation, I skipped OnColumnChanged and OnColumnChanging as I thought it would trigger with changes on a DataColumn object. But yeah, this is the exact event to hook onto to get the extra details that OnRowChanging does not provide.

Answer (score 1):

for the `RowChanging` event, if the action is `Change` you can use the `DataRow` indexer that takes the `DataRowVersion` parameter in order to get the old and the new value.
similar approach can be taken for the `RowChanged` event.

Answer (score 1):

Can [`ColumnChanging Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columnchanging.aspx) be of any help?